# ParallelTable and Random

Tags: parallelization, random

Each time I execute the following code it generates the same cylinders with the same format.

```
SeedRandom[157]
cylinders = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {50}];
SeedRandom[157]
ImageCrop[
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
     Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
     Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ cylinders, Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 800]]
```

[image]
However,

```
SeedRandom[157]
cylinders = 
  ParallelTable[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], 
    RandomReal[5]}, {50}];
SeedRandom[157]
ImageCrop[
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
     Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
     Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ cylinders, Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 800]]
```

[image]

does not exhibit the same behavior. 
I guess I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: SeedRandom is only set for the main kernel, not for the subkernels. Even when you would set it in each subkernel, I think you will get a result different from the first one.

Comment: Related [example in the documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0g7ggpmjous-ivxah).

Comment: I hope this is not marked as on hold:-)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ParallelEvaluate[SeedRandom[157]]
cylinders = 
  ParallelTable[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], 
    RandomReal[5]}, {50}];
SeedRandom[157]
ImageCrop[
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
     Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
     Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ cylinders, Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 800]]
```

[image]

```
ParallelEvaluate[SeedRandom[157 + $KernelID]]
cylinders = 
  ParallelTable[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], 
    RandomReal[5]}, {50}];
SeedRandom[157]
ImageCrop[
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
     Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
     Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ cylinders, Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 800]]
```

[image]

Comment: Karsten, note that evaluating the second `SeedRandom` in parallel doesn't keep the coloring repeatable. I think that the second call should simply be to the local master kernel, i.e. no `ParallelEvaluate` there.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks! Fixed it.

Comment: Why the first image contains fewer cylinders?

Comment: @dimitris Because all kernels produce the same cylinders.

Comment: @dimitris Compare for example `Length@cylinders` with `Length@DeleteDuplicates@cylinders`.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Nice explanation and solution.