# Random Seed and Parallelization in Compiled Functions

Tags: parallelization, random, compile

I am having trouble reproducing a random number from a compiled function with parallelization even with the random seed being set.

Specifically, running the following script should give the same value (the 3-dimensional vector) over time.

```
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   RandomReal[x]
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];
args = Range[3];
f[args]
```

However, I first got `{0.0607303, 0.00332708, 2.55753}` first. Next time `{0.468316, 0.0823131, 1.02696}` after I quit the kernel in between.

I tried the same thing with `SeedRandom[1, Method -> "ParallelMersenneTwister"];`, `SeedRandom[1, Method -> "ExtendedCA"];`, etc., and other seed numbers, which did not help.

Removing `Parallelization -> True` would resolve the issue, but

(1) is there any way to get the random seed to work properly in compiled, parallelized functions; and

(2) could someone explain how parallelization works when it comes to random number generation?

Comment: Some related Q&A: [(99786)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99786), [(100833)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100833), [(185772)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/185772)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. ```ParallelEvaluate[SeedRandom[157 + $KernelID]]``` or ```ParallelEvaluate[SeedRandom[157]]``` (with or without specific ```Method```) as suggested there did not give reproducibility in my case even though they work in the examples from the previous posts that you refer to.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.